# Http Request being blocked by the Hosting provider?

Tags: php, http, https, webserver, httpwebrequest

I have a simple Php server which is expecting the simple http get request and then Respond with some encrypted data
The http web request is made by a small application which uses wininet.dll to make the web request.

when I make the same request using a browser , everything works fine and intended data is echoed from the server , however when I make the request from the application , it gets blocked by the hosting provider.

**this is my PHP server :**

```
<?php
$entityBody = htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]);


$rest = substr($entityBody, 0, 2);
    
$str2 = substr($entityBody, 2); 

$vval= file_get_contents("Private/$str2");

$cipher     = 'AES-256-ECB';
$key        = 'FFv3mgc21VgTcaFDOPzgl5hZsY74TcTh';
$plaintext  = $vval;

if (strlen($plaintext) % 16) {
    $plaintext = str_pad($plaintext, strlen($plaintext) + 16 - strlen($plaintext) % 16, "\0");
}
$chiperRaw  = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING);
$ciphertext = trim(base64_encode($chiperRaw));

$ciphertext = $rest.$ciphertext;
 
echo($ciphertext);
?>
```

**and this is the response I get when I make the request using the Application:**

[image]

what could cause this issue ?

Comment: Looks like you're using Cloudflare. If you have access to it, log in, check the Security section, and see if you can see why it's being blocked.

Comment: The application (written in wininet.dll) may not be generating normal http_user_agent on visit to the web server , hence blocked by rules imposed (rules can be applied in .htaccess or individual .conf file, etc, or thru some sort of security service). To fix the problem, please amend your application to have the normal user agent header, etc.

Comment: Yes the problem was with the user agent being sent in the request header , 
changed the user agent to this worked :"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"